# Merge cells of NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

Is there any way to merge cell's in a NSTableView?

I know there are two modes for displaying data in a NSTableView: cell-based and view-based. If the data are presented by cells, the function

```
tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn:  NSTableColumn?, row: Int)
```

is responsable, otherwise

```
tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int)
```

Currently I'm using the first one. In iOS, you can use the cell prototype in interface builder to link the views with a custom UITableViewCell, but how can I achieve this for a complete row in a NSTableView?

Comment: No, `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` is a view based table view method. "This method is required if you want to use NSView objects instead of NSCell objects for the cells within a table view."

Comment: Documentation: [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I think you might be confusing "cells" with an individual square in a table. A _cell_, in Cocoa-speak, is an object that performs the rendering of a view (typically, a control). For example, an `NSButton` has a `NSButtonCell` object that actually does the drawing. If you want to "merge" the cells of a row and use a single view to draw the entire row, you need to implement `- [NSTableViewDelegate tableView:rowViewForRow:]`. That method gets called first, and if it returns a view, that view is used for the entire row.

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm not sure that's correct. But there is a way for table delegate to specify which rows show individual views and which ones are "whole" row views. I'd start with the WWDC view-based table view videos and check out some of the sample projects—since neither the Table View Programming Guide or API documentation seem to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found a solution: You can use both

```
tableView(_:viewFor:row:)
```

and

```
tableView(:viewFor:tableColumn:row:)
```

but you have to be aware that the tableView is not using both methods for one cell (mutually exclusive).

Now you can define a xib, with a single UIView in it. Change the class of the UIView to NSTableRowView. Next, load the class in viewDidLoad into your table:

```
if let nib: NSNib = NSNib(nibNamed: NSNib.Name("SpecialRow"), bundle: nil) {
    self.tableView?.register(nib, forIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("specialRow"));
}
```

In your table method rowViewForRow you can do the following:

```
if let srow: SpecialRow = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "specialRow"), owner: nil) as? SpecialRow {
    // ...

    return srow;
}
```